# Which inversion circle for an extension of shoemaker's knife figure involving 3 families of circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the following figure $p_n$ are the radii of the red circles, $q_n$ are the radii of the green circles, and $r_n$ are the radii of the yellow circles. Then we have

$$\frac{9}{p_{n}^2}+ \frac{4}{q_n^2} + \frac{144}{r_n^2}=\frac{32}{q_nr_n} + \frac{40}{r_np_n} + \frac{4}{p_nq_n}$$
[image]

What I thought: 
Inversion with pole B and power $\alpha = BA^2=a^2$

Being the vertices $ D, C, A, B $, respectively.

But I think that it would give a lot of computations.

Comment: If you mean $B$ is the lower right corner, then I think your idea is correct and this will allow you to compute all the radii $r_i, p_i, q_i$ easily. However some calculation is inavoidable, as you can see from the final formula to prove. But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem

Comment: A few observations make your life easier. The two circle forming [shoemaker's knife](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMAT6680.2000/Westmoreland/Essay1/Essay1.html) are tangent at the center of inversion. They transform into parallel lines. The third circle scooping the big yellow circle is perpendicular to them. So, it transform into a line perpendicular to the two parallel lines. The transforms of all yellow circles will be circles of the same radii, and so will be the transforms of the red and green circles.

Comment: Let's say $a = 1$. Under inversion against the unit circle centered at lower right corner. Your circles get mapped to a bunch of circles whose center coordinates and radii  are small rational numbers. it is not that hard to invert them back to get the radii you want.

Comment: Also, you will use [this formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Circular_Inversion#3._General_Formula_for_the_Radius_of_a_Circle_in_Terms_of_the_Radius_of_its_Inverse_Circle) repeatedly.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title "Inversion circle" which was too simple into one which could be more attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, we will assume the side of the square is $a = 1$.

Choose a coordinate system where the square becomes $[-1,0]\times[0,1]$.
Label the vertices of the square as illustrated below:
$$A = (-1,0), B = (0,0), C = (0,1),  D = (-1,1)$$

[image: Shoemaker's knife and its image]

In order to present everything in a single figure, instead of a single circle inversion, we will first apply an inversion with respect to the unit circle centered at $B$ (the orange circle), followed by a reflection with respect to the $y$-axis to the configuration at hand. i.e. apply the map

$$(x,y)\quad \mapsto \quad \left(-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$
to the source square.

Under this map, the red and green quarter circles get mapped to rays on the line $x = \frac12$ and $y = \frac12$ respectively. The blue semicircle get mapped to a ray on the line $x = 1$.

The bunch of yellow circles in the source square get mapped to another bunch of circles sandwiched between the lines $x = \frac12$ and $x = 1$. So the radii of the image circles are $R_r = \frac14$. Notice the largest yellow circle get mapped to one touching above $3$ lines, the center of its image is $(\frac34,\frac34)$. Since other yellow image circles are stacked on top of this, the center of $n^{th}$ image yellow circle is $(x_{rn},y_{rn}) = \left(\frac34, \frac{2n+1}{4}\right)$. Reflect and invert them back, the radius of $n^{th}$ yellow circle in source square is

$$r_n = \frac{R_r}{x_{rn}^2 + y_{rn}^2 - R_r^2} = \frac{4}{4n^2+4n+9}$$

Under same map, each red circle in the source square get mapped to a circle in the interstitial space formed among two yellow image circles and the red line $x = \frac12$. It is not hard to work out its radius: $R_p = \frac{1}{16}$.
From this, one find the center of 
$n^{th}$ image red circle is located at $(x_{pn},y_{pn}) = \left(\frac{9}{16}, \frac{n+1}{2}\right)$. Reflect and invert them back, one get

$$p_n = \frac{R_p}{x_{pn}^2 + y_{pn}^2 - R_p^2} = \frac{1}{4n^2 + 8n+ 9}$$

Similarly, the radii of the green image circles is $R_q = \frac{1}{16}$ and the center of $n^{th}$ image green circles is 
$(x_{qn},y_{qn}) = \left(\frac{15}{16}, \frac{n+1}{2}\right)$.

Reflect and invert the last time, one get

$$q_n = \frac{R_q}{x_{qn}^2 + y_{qn}^2 - R_q^2} = \frac{1}{4n^2 + 8n+ 18
}$$

As a double check, with help of a CAS, these three sequences of radii satisfy the identity in question:

$$\frac{9}{p_{n}^2}+ \frac{4}{q_n^2} + \frac{144}{r_n^2}=\frac{32}{q_nr_n} + \frac{40}{r_np_n} + \frac{4}{p_nq_n}$$

In above derivation, there are only two results that are not immediately obvious:

1. Why $R_p = R_q = \frac{1}{16}$ ?
2. When one reflect and invert an image circle centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $R$ back, why the radius of original circle is $\frac{R}{x^2+y^2 - R^2}$?

Both of them are not that hard to show. I will leave the first one as exercise. For the second one, it is the [formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Circular_Inversion#3._General_Formula_for_the_Radius_of_a_Circle_in_Terms_of_the_Radius_of_its_Inverse_Circle) pointed out by conditionalMethod in comment. Follow above link for more details.